# Trigger an Email when one cell is NO and one cell is YES

Tags: google-sheets

Let me begin by saying I am very weak in JS or any coding.  In the past I have been able to scrape together code from other people's forum posts, but this one is too complex for me to fumble through I guess.  I cannot figure out how to modify code I found to do this with 1 cell to do 2 cell conditions.

What I need:

1. I want to trigger an email when one cell value is No and another is Yes. Column F=No and Column I=Yes
2. I want the email to contain the data from the entire row in the email body.

I do not know if this is possible, but if it is I sure would appreciate some help.  I've posted a link to a test spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iz5qBnC08JKQDsGFT7fYkULtSHBEVyGiWFDmakLCA8c/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance to anyone who can assist!

Comment: Have you seen the [Simple Mail Merge tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge)?  I think it will get you a starting point.  In that they look for a cell to contain data.  You would modify that section to test your two cells and then you should probably set the values of at least one of these cells to the opposite so you don't send future emails for the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this gives you a start. Customize it according to your requirement.

```
  function sendMail() {
       var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("VILINKLEADS");
       var data = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow()-1,ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();

       for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
         if(data[i][5] == "No" && data[i][8] == "Yes"){
             var mailContent ='<table border="1" style="text-align:left;">'+
             '<tr><th>Customer Name</th><td>'+data[i][1]+'</td></tr>'+
             '<tr><th>Customer Number</th><td>'+data[i][2]+'</td></tr>'+
             '<tr><th>Lab Contact:</th><td>'+data[i][3]+'</td></tr>'+
             '<tr><th>Does this customer have ViLink installed anywhere in the facility?</th><td>'+data[i][5]+'</td></tr>'+
             '<tr><th>Engage the customer about the benefits of BioMerieux Remote Solutions</th><td>'+data[i][6]+'</td></tr>'+
             '<tr><th>Has this customer purchased a Vidas 3?</th><td>'+data[i][7]+'</td></tr>'+
             '<tr><th>Are there data ports available within 15 Feet of the Lab PC\'s?</th><td>'+data[i][9]+'</td></tr>'+
             '<tr><th>Model PC</th><td>'+data[i][10]+'</td></tr>'+
             '<tr><th>FSE/FAS Name:</th><td>'+data[i][11]+'</td></tr>'+
             '<tr><th>Customer Location</th><td>'+data[i][12]+'</td></tr>'+
             '<tr><th>Field Connectivity Specialist:</th><td>'+data[i][13]+'</td></tr>'+
             '<tr><th>Additional Notes from FSE/FAS</th><td>'+data[i][14]+'</td></tr>'+
             '<tr><th>FCS Notes:</th><td>'+data[i][15]+'</td></tr>'+
             '</table>';
            MailApp.sendEmail({
              to: "rrrrrr@gmail.com",
              subject: "Test Mail", //customize the subject
              htmlBody: mailContent,
              name: 'Auto Mailer'
            })
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Ritz thank you so much!  In the line that states to: data[I][4], is that pulling an email from the sheet to send to?  How would rewrite that to always send to the same email?

Comment: Ritz so I get no errors now on the email portion at the bottom, thanks so much.  One last question.  if(data[i][5] == "No" && data[i][8] == "Yes"){               The [I][5] and [I][8] are telling it what cell to look in to make its logic correct?  So to use only a column would I just use [x]?  I can't thank you enough for your help.                                                                                                            if(data[8] == "No" && data[10] == "Yes"){

Comment: @RandyBerry, as per your question you needed cell values of a particular column, which you can achieve using above code. In data[i][8], 'i' indicates the row number and 8 is the column number.

Comment: I think I know why this isn't working but I am not sure how to fix it.                 if(data[b][8] == "No" && data[b][11] == "Yes"){           this will only look at row 2 column K, I need it to run whenever a new set of data comes in.  So it won't always be row 2 but will be the highest value row with data.  Did it just get way too complicated?